# new cron script to check for davmail pid, if running do nothing. If not running restart

Tags: bash

Adopted this script based off one I found Googling, however if Davmail is running the script kills it. If Davmail is not running the script does not start it. What am I doing wrong?  I've verified the status codes by running `pgrep -f davmail | wc -w`

```
    #!/bin/bash
case "$(pgrep -f davmail | wc -w)" in

0) echo "Restarting DavMail:        $(date)" >> /var/log/davmail.txt
   /home/user/Downloads/davmail-linux-x86_64-4.8.0-2479/davmail.sh &
   ;;
1) # all ok
   ;;
*) echo "Removed double Davmail:    $(date)" >> /var/log/davmail.txt
   kill $(pgrep -f davmail | awk '{print $1}')
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: just remove the dbl-quotes around `"$( pgrep -f ...)"` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've verified the status codes by running `pgrep -f davmail | wc -w`

That's not how you verify status codes.
You can verify status codes by checking the value of `$?`.

But the real issue here is that the output of `wc -w` is padded with spaces, and you double-quoted the value in `case "..." in`,
so only the `*)` will match.

Another problem is that although the comment says "Removed double Davmail",
the command there will kill all the matching processes,
not just the "double Davmail".
If you intend to keep one process and kill all the others,
you need to fix that.

Here's one way to fix the above issues:

```
count=$(pgrep -f davmail | wc -w)
if [ $count = 0 ]; then
    echo "Restarting DavMail:        $(date)" >> /var/log/davmail.txt
    /home/user/Downloads/davmail-linux-x86_64-4.8.0-2479/davmail.sh &
elif [ $count != 1 ]; then
    echo "Removed double Davmail:    $(date)" >> /var/log/davmail.txt
    kill $(pgrep -f davmail | sed -e 1d)
fi
```

Comment: Thanks janos.  Using your variant I'm still having an issue.
`15:57:13  bhart@Vostok  /etc/cron.d 
$ pgrep -f davmail | wc -w  
0

 15:57:23  bhart@Vostok  /etc/cron.d 
$ sudo ./davmail_check.sh   
[1]    26216 terminated  sudo ./davmail_check.sh`

Ther eis no davmail processes running, however the script just returns a terminated... unless it's seeing the grep as a pis to be terminated?

Comment: @Skeer since code blocks in comments are not formatted well, it's very hard to make out what's going on there. But it looks like it's the `sudo ./davmail_check.sh` getting terminated, which was not part of your posted code in the question. Maybe you want to post a new question with more details of this new scenario.

Comment: No I was just calling the script in question manually is all.  Is that not an appropriate way to test? I could maybe toss this into an IDE and run it from there..

Comment: @Skeer definitely better to test by running the script and NOT from an IDE, ever. And oh I see it now. Yeah the `pgrep` will match your script `davmail_check.sh` and so the script kills itself :-) So you need to make sure that does not happen, either by changing the pattern or the name of the script

Comment: I was worried about that.. or the pgrep finding the grep pid.. lol.  I'll explore the process names a bi tmore

Comment: ok I changed the pgrep from davmail to davmail.jar (which is called by davmail.sh).  I got no errors running it.  Killed davmail, ran script and davmail was started but I did get an error about not being able to set the log file path.
`2017-08-29 09:15:17,943 ERROR [main] davmail  - Unable to set log file path
2017-08-29 09:15:17,944 ERROR [main] davmail  - Unable to set log file path
`

Comment: @Skeer I don't see how that's related to this script, I think that's an entirely different question

Comment: Not saying it is.. Just reporting back. I gave you a point :) Thanks for your time and help!!